# How to reload the indexPath of the collectionviewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently working on an app that has a table-view-like collection view and some other view controllers. Basically, my question is how can I update the indexPath of each cell when one of the collection view cells is deleted.

I attached my view controller file below, but here is what's going on on the app.
When a user opens the table-view-like collection view (in EventCollectionVC), it reloads the data from a database and presents them on the collection view. I also added the code to the navigation bar button item that the user can change the collection view to the edit mode. While in the edit mode, a small ellipsis.circle (SF symbols) is displayed on the collection view cell. When a user taps the ellipsis.circle icon, it displays a new view controller (ModalVC) and lets the user select either delete or edit the cell. When the user selects delete, it shows an alert to delete the cell and delete the cell information with modal dismiss (which means the ModalVC is closed and the MyCollectionVC is displayed now).

Since I have to make the two view controllers (like getting cell information from EventCollectionVC and present in ModalVC) talk to each other, I need to use the indexPath.row to get the information of the cell. Before deleting the cells, the numbers of indexPath.row in the collection view is like

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

But, for example, after I delete the second (indexPath.row = 1) cell and when I try to delete another item, the indexPath becomes

```
[0,2,3,4,5]
```

and I can see the collection view's index is not refreshed.

So my question is how can I update/refresh the cell's indexPath.row value after I delete a cell from the collection view?

This is the code with some explanations.

```
import UIKit

class EvnetCollectionViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var EventDataSource: EventDataSource! // <- this is a class for the Model, and it stores array or Events
    let ListView = ListView() // view file
    var collectionViewDataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Event>?
    var targetEventIndex = Int() // variable to store the index of the event when event cell is tapped
    
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = ListView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureNavItem()
        setupCollectionView()
        displayEvents()
    }
    
    func configureNavItem() {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    }
    
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        
        if (editing){
            ListView.collectionView.isEditing = true
        } else {
            ListView.collectionView.isEditing = false
        }
    }
    
    func setupCollectionView() {
        
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Event> { cell, indexPath, Event in
            
            var content = UIListContentConfiguration.cell()
            content.text = Event.title
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
            
            let moreAction = UIAction(image: UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis.circle"),
                                                  handler: { _ in
                                                    let vc = EventActionModalViewController(); // when the user select the cell in edit mode, it displays action modal VC and then come back to this VC with dismiss later
                                                    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
                                                    self.targetEventIndex = indexPath.row　// I need targetEvemtIndex when user selects delete event in EventActionModalVC, so just sotre value in here
                                                  })
            
            let moreActionButton = UIButton(primaryAction: moreAction)
            let moreActionAccessory = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(
                customView: moreActionButton,
                placement: .trailing(displayed: .whenEditing, at: { _ in return 0 })
            )
            
            cell.accessories = [
                .disclosureIndicator(displayed: .whenNotEditing),
                .customView(configuration: moreActionAccessory)
            ]
        }
        
        collectionViewDataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Event>(collectionView: ListView.collectionView) {
            collectionView, indexPath, Event in
            collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: Event)
        }
    }
    
    func displayEvents() {
        EventDataSource = EventDataSource()
        EventDataSource.loadData() // get Events in db and sore in an array Events
        populate(with: EventDataSource.Events)
    }
    
    func populate(with Events: [Event]) {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Event>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.List])
        snapshot.appendItems(Events)
        collectionViewDataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
    
    func showDeleteAlert() {
        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { _ in
                self.EventDataSource.delete(at: targetEventIndex)
                self.refreshList()
            }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
            
        self.showAlert(title: "Delete", message: nil, actions: [deleteAction, cancelAction], style: .actionSheet, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func refreshList() {
        EventDataSource.loadData()
        
        setupCollectionView() // since I write this code, it updates all of the indexPath in the collection view, but after deleting one item, the whole collection view is deleted and new collection view is reappeared. 
        populate(with: EventDataSource.Events)
    }

}
```

I kinda know why this is happening. I only configure cell (in let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Event>...) once, so it won't update the cell information as well as its index path until I configure it again. But if I call setupCollectionView every after deleting one item, the whole collection view disappears and shows up again. Is it possible to reload the collection view list and updates its information without reloading the entire collection view?

Without writing setupCollectionView() in refreshList, the cell's indexPath is not refreshed and I get an error after I delete one cell and try to delete another one. So, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid recreating the whole collection view but update cells' indexPath when the user delete one of the cell in collection view.

Comment: You are using a diffable data source, so you don't need to worry about index paths.  You should delete the relevant element from your model.  Then you need to signal your other view controller(s) that they need to re-apply the snapshot.  You could use a delegation pattern or a `Notification` or even Combine.

Comment: How are you getting [0,2,3,4,5]?  Have you removed the item whose index == 1 in your dataset?

Comment: on place of setupCollectionView() try to write `collectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: @ShivamParmar you mean in the refresh list function?

Comment: @ElTomato I write a print statement for checking the indexPath when the user tries to delete the item from the list. Then after I deleted one cell, the value of indexPath.row skips the number for indexParh.row, which I just deleted. 

So like If I have three items on the list and after I delete the second item in the list (which means there are two items in the list), the indexpath.row of the first item is the same (0), but the second one becomes 2. <- I want to make this value to 1.

btw, I think you helped me in other StackOverflow posts, so thank you for your kind help everytime.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your reply. I think I get it most part, but not really sure how I can re-apply the snapshot to my EventCollectionVC. Is there a method that I can re-apply shaphot???

Also, you mean I write the re-apply function in EventCollectionVC and call the method after the user hits the deleteAction in showDeleteAlert?

Comment: yes in refresh list function on place of setupCollectionView() try to write collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: @ShivamParmar I tried that but still gives me the error, Fatal error: Index out of range error.

Here is the log for what is going on.
EventDataSource.Events -> Event(id: 1, title: "First Event"), Event(id: 2, title: "Second Event"), Event(id: 3, title: "Third Event ")
targetEventIndex -> 1

Then deleted the second item.

EventDataSource.Events -> Event(id: 1, title: "First Event"), Event(id: 3, title: "Third Event ")
Wehn I select "Third Event", it gives me an index of 2.
targetEventIndex -> 2

Comment: Just call `populate(with: EventDataSource.Events)` again; assuming `EventDataSource.Events` has been updated.  Each item in the array that populates a diffable data source must support `Identifiable` - This is what lets a diffable data source do its magic - By examining the `id` of each element, the collection view will know which element has been deleted.

Comment: You need to ensure that your events have a unique identifier that doesn't change.  You should never deal with index paths; You should tell your model to delete the specific `Event` object, or its `id` - Have the model go through the array and remove the specified event

Comment: @ShivamParmar Actually, you are right. I worte         liveListView.collectionView.reloadData() but in a wrong order. Writing reloadData() works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code in the refresh list function.

```
func refreshList() {
    self.EventDataSource.loadData()
    self.populate(with: self.EventDataSource.Events)
    ListView.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

I just needed to call reloadData after I populate all the data...